# launchctl list shows bundle identifiers of running application, there is a number after that what is it?

Tags: launchd

command and its output

```
launchctl list  | grep Terminal

94502   0   com.apple.Terminal.2000
```

What is the 2000 number referring to?
 94502 is Pid and
 0 is exit status

What does it mean if pid is empty _.

```
_   0   com.apple.Terminal.2000
```

What is the difference between this and LaunchAgent/LaunchDaemonservices